# Why is my recursive function not looping through my JSON correctly?

Tags: javascript, json

*RECENTLY EDITED TO BE SHORTER*

This might be a long shot asking this here, but I need help with a recursive function I have created. It is not getting me the values I want from the JSON. Basically I want to get all "Flow" object IDs that have a "Type" of "Standard" OR "Block". The objects could be nested in multiple "Flow" objects under the parent "Flow" object, which is why I need a recursive method to search for all of them.  I created a codepen so you can see the result I am getting here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YdVyYG?editors=1012

The function is at the bottom and it's called "GroupRecursion", which I pass the JSON "Payload" as a parameter.

I am only getting about 3 IDs (Strings) in my array called ArrayOfBlockIDs, I should be getting exactly 4 strings since that is how many objects have "Type" = "Standard" or "Block". Thanks for your time, if this is not the place for this, let me know.

```
var Payload = {
    "Type": "Root",
    "FlowID": "FL_1",
    "Flow": [
      {
        "Type": "Group",
        "FlowID": "FL_27",
        "Description": "Pass 1",
        "Flow": [
          {
            "Type": "EmbeddedData",
            "FlowID": "FL_7",
            "EmbeddedData": [
              {
                "Description": "JSON",
                "Type": "Recipient",
                "Field": "JSON",
                "VariableType": "String",
                "DataVisibility": [],
                "AnalyzeText": false
              },
              {
                "Description": "DisplayLogicFrom",
                "Type": "Recipient",
                "Field": "DisplayLogicFrom",
                "VariableType": "String",
                "DataVisibility": [],
                "AnalyzeText": false
              },
              {
                "Description": "DisplayLogicAt",
                "Type": "Recipient",
                "Field": "DisplayLogicAt",
                "VariableType": "String",
                "DataVisibility": [],
                "AnalyzeText": false
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Type": "Branch",
            "FlowID": "FL_54",
            "Description": "New Branch",
            "BranchLogic": {
              "0": {
                "0": {
                  "LogicType": "EmbeddedField",
                  "LeftOperand": "APITest",
                  "Operator": "EqualTo",
                  "RightOperand": "True",
                  "_HiddenExpression": false,
                  "Type": "Expression",
                  "Description": "<span class=\"ConjDesc\">If</span>  <span class=\"LeftOpDesc\">APITest</span> <span class=\"OpDesc\">Is Equal to</span> <span class=\"RightOpDesc\"> True </span>"
                },
                "Type": "If"
              },
              "Type": "BooleanExpression"
            },
            "Flow": [
              {
                "Type": "Standard",
                "ID": "BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf",
                "FlowID": "FL_51"
              },
              {
                "Type": "Standard",
                "ID": "BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt",
                "FlowID": "FL_59"
              },
              {
                "Type": "WebService",
                "FlowID": "FL_50",
                "URL": "https://co1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys",
                "Method": "POST",
                "RequestParams": [],
                "EditBodyParams": [
                  {
                    "key": "file",
                    "value": "${e://Field/TEST}"
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "name",
                    "value": "new survey"
                  }
                ],
                "Body": [
                  {
                    "key": "file",
                    "value": "${e://Field/TEST}"
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "name",
                    "value": "new survey"
                  }
                ],
                "ContentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Headers": [
                  {
                    "key": "x-api-token",
                    "value": "h69TKYgxu46SMEXzcKkeRUXovq2jALTpHDhPUGLq"
                  }
                ],
                "ResponseMap": [
                  {
                    "key": "meta.requestId",
                    "value": "meta.requestId"
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "meta.error.errorCode",
                    "value": "meta.error.errorCode"
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "meta.error.errorMessage",
                    "value": "meta.error.errorMessage"
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "meta.httpStatus",
                    "value": "meta.httpStatus"
                  }
                ],
                "FireAndForget": false,
                "SchemaVersion": 0,
                "StringifyValues": true
              },
              {
                "Type": "Standard",
                "ID": "BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B",
                "FlowID": "FL_53"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Type": "Standard",
            "ID": "BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141",
            "FlowID": "FL_3"
          },
          {
            "Type": "Branch",
            "FlowID": "FL_5",
            "Description": "New Branch",
            "BranchLogic": {
              "0": {
                "0": {
                  "LogicType": "Question",
                  "QuestionID": "QID4",
                  "QuestionIsInLoop": "no",
                  "ChoiceLocator": "q://QID4/SelectableChoice/1",
                  "Operator": "Selected",
                  "QuestionIDFromLocator": "QID4",
                  "LeftOperand": "q://QID4/SelectableChoice/1",
                  "Type": "Expression",
                  "Description": "<span class=\"ConjDesc\">If</span> <span class=\"QuestionDesc\">What would you like to do?</span> <span class=\"LeftOpDesc\">Check if there is custom validation/Force Response on my survey and on what questions</span> <span class=\"OpDesc\">Is Selected</span> "
                },
                "Type": "If"
              },
              "Type": "BooleanExpression"
            },
            "Flow": [
              {
                "Type": "Block",
                "ID": "BL_3n1Vmp4FL6cZZuR",
                "FlowID": "FL_2"
              },
              {
                "Type": "EndSurvey",
                "FlowID": "FL_11"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Type": "Branch",
            "FlowID": "FL_56",
            "Description": "New Branch",
            "BranchLogic": {
              "0": {
                "0": {
                  "LogicType": "Question",
                  "QuestionID": "QID4",
                  "QuestionIsInLoop": "no",
                  "ChoiceLocator": "q://QID4/SelectableChoice/6",
                  "Operator": "Selected",
                  "QuestionIDFromLocator": "QID4",
                  "LeftOperand": "q://QID4/SelectableChoice/6",
                  "Type": "Expression",
                  "Description": "<span class=\"ConjDesc\">If</span> <span class=\"QuestionDesc\">What would you like to do?</span> <span class=\"LeftOpDesc\">Re-Number the questions to be in order but add \"TEXT\" to descriptive text questions.</span> <span class=\"OpDesc\">Is Selected</span> "
                },
                "Type": "If"
              },
              "Type": "BooleanExpression"
            },
            "Flow": [
              {
                "Type": "Standard",
                "ID": "BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx",
                "FlowID": "FL_60"
              },
              {
                "ID": "BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9",
                "Type": "Standard",
                "FlowID": "FL_61"
              },
              {
                "Type": "Standard",
                "ID": "BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV",
                "FlowID": "FL_55"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Type": "Branch",
            "FlowID": "FL_58",
            "Description": "New Branch",
            "BranchLogic": {
              "0": {
                "0": {
                  "LogicType": "Question",
                  "QuestionID": "QID4",
                  "QuestionIsInLoop": "no",
                  "ChoiceLocator": "q://QID4/SelectableChoice/6",
                  "Operator": "NotSelected",
                  "QuestionIDFromLocator": "QID4",
                  "LeftOperand": "q://QID4/SelectableChoice/6",
                  "Type": "Expression",
                  "Description": "<span class=\"ConjDesc\">If</span> <span class=\"QuestionDesc\">What would you like to do?</span> <span class=\"LeftOpDesc\">Re-Number the questions to be in order but add \"TEXT\" to descriptive text questions.</span> <span class=\"OpDesc\">Is Not Selected</span> "
                },
                "Type": "If"
              },
              "Type": "BooleanExpression"
            },
            "Flow": [
              {
                "Type": "Standard",
                "ID": "BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1",
                "FlowID": "FL_13"
              },
              {
                "Type": "EmbeddedData",
                "FlowID": "FL_14",
                "EmbeddedData": [
                  {
                    "Description": "APIToken",
                    "Type": "Custom",
                    "Field": "APIToken",
                    "VariableType": "String",
                    "DataVisibility": [],
                    "AnalyzeText": false,
                    "Value": "${q://QID18/ChoiceTextEntryValue/2}"
                  },
                  {
                    "Description": "Datacenter",
                    "Type": "Custom",
                    "Field": "Datacenter",
                    "VariableType": "String",
                    "DataVisibility": [],
                    "AnalyzeText": false,
                    "Value": "${q://QID18/ChoiceTextEntryValue/1}"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "Type": "Standard",
                "ID": "BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz",
                "FlowID": "FL_4"
              },
              {
                "Type": "Branch",
                "FlowID": "FL_21",
                "Description": "New Branch",
                "BranchLogic": {
                  "0": {
                    "0": {
                      "LogicType": "Question",
                      "QuestionID": "QID17",
                      "QuestionIsInLoop": "no",
                      "ChoiceLocator": "q://QID17/SelectableChoice/4",
                      "Operator": "Selected",
                      "QuestionIDFromLocator": "QID17",
                      "LeftOperand": "q://QID17/SelectableChoice/4",
                      "Type": "Expression",
                      "Description": "<span class=\"ConjDesc\">If</span> <span class=\"QuestionDesc\">What type of questions will you be using?</span> <span class=\"LeftOpDesc\">matrix choice to multiple choice question</span> <span class=\"OpDesc\">Is Selected</span> "
                    },
                    "Type": "If"
                  },
                  "Type": "BooleanExpression"
                },
                "Flow": [
                  {
                    "Type": "Standard",
                    "ID": "BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz",
                    "FlowID": "FL_20"
                  },
                  {
                    "Type": "Standard",
                    "ID": "BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr",
                    "FlowID": "FL_23"
                  },
                  {
                    "Type": "EmbeddedData",
                    "FlowID": "FL_25",
                    "EmbeddedData": [
                      {
                        "Description": "Conjunction",
                        "Type": "Custom",
                        "Field": "Conjunction",
                        "VariableType": "String",
                        "DataVisibility": [],
                        "AnalyzeText": false,
                        "Value": "${q://QID32/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "Type": "EmbeddedData",
                    "FlowID": "FL_26",
                    "EmbeddedData": [
                      {
                        "Description": "Operator",
                        "Type": "Custom",
                        "Field": "Operator",
                        "VariableType": "String",
                        "DataVisibility": [],
                        "AnalyzeText": false,
                        "Value": "${q://QID29/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "Type": "Standard",
                    "ID": "BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp",
                    "FlowID": "FL_24"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "Type": "Branch",
                "FlowID": "FL_6",
                "Description": "New Branch",
                "BranchLogic": {
                  "0": {
                    "0": {
                      "LogicType": "Question",
                      "QuestionID": "QID17",
                      "QuestionIsInLoop": "no",
                      "ChoiceLocator": "q://QID17/SelectableChoice/1",
                      "Operator": "Selected",
                      "QuestionIDFromLocator": "QID17",
                      "LeftOperand": "q://QID17/SelectableChoice/1",
                      "Type": "Expression",
                      "Description": "<span class=\"ConjDesc\">If</span> <span class=\"QuestionDesc\">What type of questions will you be using?</span> <span class=\"LeftOpDesc\">multiple choice to multiple choice</span> <span class=\"OpDesc\">Is Selected</span> "
                    },
                    "Type": "If"
                  },
                  "Type": "BooleanExpression"
                },
                "Flow": [
                  {
                    "Type": "EmbeddedData",
                    "FlowID": "FL_10",
                    "EmbeddedData": [
                      {
                        "Description": "Operator",
                        "Type": "Custom",
                        "Field": "Operator",
                        "VariableType": "String",
                        "DataVisibility": [],
                        "AnalyzeText": false,
                        "Value": "${q://QID13/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "Type": "Standard",
                    "ID": "BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV",
                    "FlowID": "FL_19"
                  },
                  {
                    "Type": "Standard",
                    "ID": "BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP",
                    "FlowID": "FL_9"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Type": "Standard",
            "ID": "BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr",
            "FlowID": "FL_28"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Type": "Standard",
        "ID": "BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5",
        "FlowID": "FL_17"
      },
      {
        "Type": "EndSurvey",
        "FlowID": "FL_16"
      },
      {
        "Type": "WebService",
        "FlowID": "FL_15",
        "URL": "https://co1.qualtrics.com/API/v:version/surveys",
        "Method": "PUT",
        "RequestParams": [],
        "EditBodyParams": [
          {
            "key": "QuestionText",
            "value": "Hello"
          },
          {
            "key": "DataExportTag",
            "value": "Q2"
          },
          {
            "key": "QuestionType",
            "value": "MC"
          },
          {
            "key": "Selector",
            "value": "SAVR"
          },
          {
            "key": "SubSelector",
            "value": "TX"
          },
          {
            "key": "Configuration",
            "value": "{\"QuestionDescriptionOption\":\"UseText\"}",
            "parameterType": "JSON"
          },
          {
            "key": "QuestionDescription",
            "value": "Hello?"
          },
          {
            "key": "Choices",
            "value": "{\"Choices\": {\n          \"1\": {\n            \"Display\": \"Statement 1\"\n          },\n          \"2\": {\n            \"Display\": \"Statement 2\"\n          },\n          \"3\": {\n            \"Display\": \"Statement 3\"\n          }\n        }}",
            "parameterType": "JSON"
          },
          {
            "key": "Language",
            "value": "[]",
            "parameterType": "JSON"
          },
          {
            "key": "Validation",
            "value": "{\"Settings\": {\n            \"ForceResponse\": \"OFF\",\n            \"ForceResponseType\": \"ON\",\n            \"Type\": \"None\"\n          }}",
            "parameterType": "JSON"
          }
        ],
        "Body": {
          "QuestionText": "Hello",
          "DataExportTag": "Q2",
          "QuestionType": "MC",
          "Selector": "SAVR",
          "SubSelector": "TX",
          "Configuration": {
            "QuestionDescriptionOption": "UseText"
          },
          "QuestionDescription": "Hello?",
          "Choices": {
            "Choices": {
              "1": {
                "Display": "Statement 1"
              },
              "2": {
                "Display": "Statement 2"
              },
              "3": {
                "Display": "Statement 3"
              }
            }
          },
          "Language": [],
          "Validation": {
            "Settings": {
              "ForceResponse": "OFF",
              "ForceResponseType": "ON",
              "Type": "None"
            }
          }
        },
        "ContentType": "application/json",
        "Headers": [
          {
            "key": "x-api-token",
            "value": "h69TKYgxu46SMEXzcKkeRUXovq2jALTpHDhPUGLq"
          }
        ],
        "ResponseMap": [],
        "FireAndForget": false,
        "SchemaVersion": 0,
        "StringifyValues": true
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Count": 61,
      "RemovedFieldsets": []
    }
  }

    var ArrayOfBlockIDs = []
    var RecursionCount = 0;
    function GroupRecursion(item){

        for(i=0;i<item.Flow.length;i++){


            if(item.Flow[i].Type=="Standard" && ArrayOfBlockIDs.includes(item.Flow[i].ID)==false || item.Flow[i].Type=="Block" && ArrayOfBlockIDs.includes(item.Flow[i].ID)==false){
                    ArrayOfBlockIDs.push(item.Flow[i].ID)

            }

            if(item.Flow[i].Type=="Group" || item.Flow[i].Type=="Branch"){

                GroupRecursion(item.Flow[i])


            } 



        }


        console.log(ArrayOfBlockIDs)
    }

GroupRecursion(Payload);
```

//

Comment: Please reduce this to a minimal test case. That will likely lead you to the answer and even if it doesn't it'll make it easier for us to help you with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your code is a little more complex than it needs to be. I think  a simpler recursive function will find all of these. This is just a function that takes an array looks through each item for the desired Type and then passes the child Flow array back through the function:

```js
var Payload = {"Type": "Root","FlowID": "FL_1","Flow": [{"Type": "Group","FlowID": "FL_27","Description": "Pass 1","Flow": [{"Type": "EmbeddedData","FlowID": "FL_7","EmbeddedData": [{"Description": "JSON","Type": "Recipient","Field": "JSON","VariableType": "String","DataVisibility": [],"AnalyzeText": false},{"Description": "DisplayLogicFrom","Type": "Recipient","Field": "DisplayLogicFrom","VariableType": "String","DataVisibility": [],"AnalyzeText": false},{"Description": "DisplayLogicAt","Type": "Recipient","Field": "DisplayLogicAt","VariableType": "String","DataVisibility": [],"AnalyzeText": false}]},{"Type": "Branch","FlowID": "FL_54","Description": "New Branch","BranchLogic": {"0": {"0": {"LogicType": "EmbeddedField","LeftOperand": "APITest","Operator": "EqualTo","RightOperand": "True","_HiddenExpression": false,"Type": "Expression","Description": "<span class=\"ConjDesc\">If</span>  <span class=\"LeftOpDesc\">APITest</span> <span class=\"OpDesc\">Is Equal to</span> <span class=\"RightOpDesc\"> True </span>"},"Type": "If"},"Type": "BooleanExpression"},"Flow": [{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_4NL909leoyn5KBf","FlowID": "FL_51"},{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_bBGbASH2RnPCskt","FlowID": "FL_59"},{"Type": "WebService","FlowID": "FL_50","URL": "https://co1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys","Method": "POST","RequestParams": [],"EditBodyParams": [{"key": "file","value": "${e://Field/TEST}"},{"key": "name","value": "new survey"}],"Body": [{"key": "file","value": "${e://Field/TEST}"},{"key": "name","value": "new survey"}],"ContentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Headers": [{"key": "x-api-token","value": "h69TKYgxu46SMEXzcKkeRUXovq2jALTpHDhPUGLq"}],"ResponseMap": [{"key": "meta.requestId","value": "meta.requestId"},{"key": "meta.error.errorCode","value": "meta.error.errorCode"},{"key": "meta.error.errorMessage","value": "meta.error.errorMessage"},{"key": "meta.httpStatus","value": "meta.httpStatus"}],"FireAndForget": false,"SchemaVersion": 0,"StringifyValues": true},{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_4Yhl7MpygFG9Z6B","FlowID": "FL_53"}]},{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_0GHahOV7Hb9l141","FlowID": "FL_3"},{"Type": "Branch","FlowID": "FL_5","Description": "New Branch","BranchLogic": {"0": {"0": {"LogicType": "Question","QuestionID": "QID4","QuestionIsInLoop": "no","ChoiceLocator": "q://QID4/SelectableChoice/1","Operator": "Selected","QuestionIDFromLocator": "QID4","LeftOperand": "q://QID4/SelectableChoice/1","Type": "Expression","Description": "<span class=\"ConjDesc\">If</span> <span class=\"QuestionDesc\">What would you like to do?</span> <span class=\"LeftOpDesc\">Check if there is custom validation/Force Response on my survey and on what questions</span> <span class=\"OpDesc\">Is Selected</span> "},"Type": "If"},"Type": "BooleanExpression"},"Flow": [{"Type": "Block","ID": "BL_3n1Vmp4FL6cZZuR","FlowID": "FL_2"},{"Type": "EndSurvey","FlowID": "FL_11"}]},{"Type": "Branch","FlowID": "FL_56","Description": "New Branch","BranchLogic": {"0": {"0": {"LogicType": "Question","QuestionID": "QID4","QuestionIsInLoop": "no","ChoiceLocator": "q://QID4/SelectableChoice/6","Operator": "Selected","QuestionIDFromLocator": "QID4","LeftOperand": "q://QID4/SelectableChoice/6","Type": "Expression","Description": "<span class=\"ConjDesc\">If</span> <span class=\"QuestionDesc\">What would you like to do?</span> <span class=\"LeftOpDesc\">Re-Number the questions to be in order but add \"TEXT\" to descriptive text questions.</span> <span class=\"OpDesc\">Is Selected</span> "},"Type": "If"},"Type": "BooleanExpression"},"Flow": [{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_9ESRPcpuMl5TNcx","FlowID": "FL_60"},{"ID": "BL_cACgbdijKOAtRo9","Type": "Standard","FlowID": "FL_61"},{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_0SuWoa7K2CkYFsV","FlowID": "FL_55"}]},{"Type": "Branch","FlowID": "FL_58","Description": "New Branch","BranchLogic": {"0": {"0": {"LogicType": "Question","QuestionID": "QID4","QuestionIsInLoop": "no","ChoiceLocator": "q://QID4/SelectableChoice/6","Operator": "NotSelected","QuestionIDFromLocator": "QID4","LeftOperand": "q://QID4/SelectableChoice/6","Type": "Expression","Description": "<span class=\"ConjDesc\">If</span> <span class=\"QuestionDesc\">What would you like to do?</span> <span class=\"LeftOpDesc\">Re-Number the questions to be in order but add \"TEXT\" to descriptive text questions.</span> <span class=\"OpDesc\">Is Not Selected</span> "},"Type": "If"},"Type": "BooleanExpression"},"Flow": [{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_2tA1Ilad6iCEEu1","FlowID": "FL_13"},{"Type": "EmbeddedData","FlowID": "FL_14","EmbeddedData": [{"Description": "APIToken","Type": "Custom","Field": "APIToken","VariableType": "String","DataVisibility": [],"AnalyzeText": false,"Value": "${q://QID18/ChoiceTextEntryValue/2}"},{"Description": "Datacenter","Type": "Custom","Field": "Datacenter","VariableType": "String","DataVisibility": [],"AnalyzeText": false,"Value": "${q://QID18/ChoiceTextEntryValue/1}"}]},{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_0r1ZjeAhMBEBhdz","FlowID": "FL_4"},{"Type": "Branch","FlowID": "FL_21","Description": "New Branch","BranchLogic": {"0": {"0": {"LogicType": "Question","QuestionID": "QID17","QuestionIsInLoop": "no","ChoiceLocator": "q://QID17/SelectableChoice/4","Operator": "Selected","QuestionIDFromLocator": "QID17","LeftOperand": "q://QID17/SelectableChoice/4","Type": "Expression","Description": "<span class=\"ConjDesc\">If</span> <span class=\"QuestionDesc\">What type of questions will you be using?</span> <span class=\"LeftOpDesc\">matrix choice to multiple choice question</span> <span class=\"OpDesc\">Is Selected</span> "},"Type": "If"},"Type": "BooleanExpression"},"Flow": [{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_6ilSpb6iiCzWvtz","FlowID": "FL_20"},{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_a4faBNVnTi19wLr","FlowID": "FL_23"},{"Type": "EmbeddedData","FlowID": "FL_25","EmbeddedData": [{"Description": "Conjunction","Type": "Custom","Field": "Conjunction","VariableType": "String","DataVisibility": [],"AnalyzeText": false,"Value": "${q://QID32/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}"}]},{"Type": "EmbeddedData","FlowID": "FL_26","EmbeddedData": [{"Description": "Operator","Type": "Custom","Field": "Operator","VariableType": "String","DataVisibility": [],"AnalyzeText": false,"Value": "${q://QID29/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}"}]},{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_2lVBP4EOiOwT0Kp","FlowID": "FL_24"}]},{"Type": "Branch","FlowID": "FL_6","Description": "New Branch","BranchLogic": {"0": {"0": {"LogicType": "Question","QuestionID": "QID17","QuestionIsInLoop": "no","ChoiceLocator": "q://QID17/SelectableChoice/1","Operator": "Selected","QuestionIDFromLocator": "QID17","LeftOperand": "q://QID17/SelectableChoice/1","Type": "Expression","Description": "<span class=\"ConjDesc\">If</span> <span class=\"QuestionDesc\">What type of questions will you be using?</span> <span class=\"LeftOpDesc\">multiple choice to multiple choice</span> <span class=\"OpDesc\">Is Selected</span> "},"Type": "If"},"Type": "BooleanExpression"},"Flow": [{"Type": "EmbeddedData","FlowID": "FL_10","EmbeddedData": [{"Description": "Operator","Type": "Custom","Field": "Operator","VariableType": "String","DataVisibility": [],"AnalyzeText": false,"Value": "${q://QID13/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}"}]},{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_4IMpxjrEATyLuqV","FlowID": "FL_19"},{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_bBjaPeuYnHFtBBP","FlowID": "FL_9"}]}]},{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_eD0WiECJYD2l0nr","FlowID": "FL_28"}]},{"Type": "Standard","ID": "BL_1Mk6LuLiukBnCU5","FlowID": "FL_17"},{"Type": "EndSurvey","FlowID": "FL_16"},{"Type": "WebService","FlowID": "FL_15","URL": "https://co1.qualtrics.com/API/v:version/surveys","Method": "PUT","RequestParams": [],"EditBodyParams": [{"key": "QuestionText","value": "Hello"},{"key": "DataExportTag","value": "Q2"},{"key": "QuestionType","value": "MC"},{"key": "Selector","value": "SAVR"},{"key": "SubSelector","value": "TX"},{"key": "Configuration","value": "{\"QuestionDescriptionOption\":\"UseText\"}","parameterType": "JSON"},{"key": "QuestionDescription","value": "Hello?"},{"key": "Choices","value": "{\"Choices\": {\n          \"1\": {\n            \"Display\": \"Statement 1\"\n          },\n          \"2\": {\n            \"Display\": \"Statement 2\"\n          },\n          \"3\": {\n            \"Display\": \"Statement 3\"\n          }\n        }}","parameterType": "JSON"},{"key": "Language","value": "[]","parameterType": "JSON"},{"key": "Validation","value": "{\"Settings\": {\n            \"ForceResponse\": \"OFF\",\n            \"ForceResponseType\": \"ON\",\n            \"Type\": \"None\"\n          }}","parameterType": "JSON"}],"Body": {"QuestionText": "Hello","DataExportTag": "Q2","QuestionType": "MC","Selector": "SAVR","SubSelector": "TX","Configuration": {"QuestionDescriptionOption": "UseText"},"QuestionDescription": "Hello?","Choices": {"Choices": {"1": {"Display": "Statement 1"},"2": {"Display": "Statement 2"},"3": {"Display": "Statement 3"}}},"Language": [],"Validation": {"Settings": {"ForceResponse": "OFF","ForceResponseType": "ON","Type": "None"}}},"ContentType": "application/json","Headers": [{"key": "x-api-token","value": "h69TKYgxu46SMEXzcKkeRUXovq2jALTpHDhPUGLq"}],"ResponseMap": [],"FireAndForget": false,"SchemaVersion": 0,"StringifyValues": true}],"Properties": {"Count": 61,"RemovedFieldsets": []}}

function getID(arr){
  if (!arr || arr.length == 0 ) return []
  return arr.reduce((arr, item) =>{
    if (item.Type == "Standard"  || item.Type == "Block") {
      arr.push(item.ID)  
    }
    return arr.concat(getID(item.Flow))
  }, [])
}

let fl = getID([Payload])

console.log("length: ", fl.length)
console.log(fl)
```

Comment: sorry to bug you, but it looks like the IDs in the array are not in the order that they were in the Payload object (which I failed to mention was important). Is this easily fixable?

Comment: @JacobWest You usually can make the recursion do different things -- it most naturally does a depth first search through the tree . When you say original order, do you mean all of one level and then all the children in the next level?

Comment: Not exactly, I need it to be in the order they come in the object, as if you were to read it from top to bottom. The reason for this is because this is the order they come is crucial to my solution, which is numbering each object depending on the order they appear in the object.

Comment: @JacobWest So that sounds like depth first to me, which is what the above should do. Here's a simplified version with ids that make it easy to see the order: https://codepen.io/markmeyerphoto/pen/WLjrrP?editors=1111 It's the order that you find as you go down the page.

Comment: @JacobWest here's a breadth first alternative: https://codepen.io/markmeyerphoto/pen/GPmoqx

Comment: You are right, they are in order, I failed to notice that. I would say thank you very much but stackoverflow doesn't like that.